# Increase and decrease width and height of a block in a list on hover

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a list which I want to increase width and height of each block in `0.5s` while user hover it. and then decrease to the default size after mouse out again in `0.5s`.

my problem is how to set `z-index` to show it in front of the other blocks on my list while mouse hover it and then when mouse out it adjust in default size and place

this is my html list:

```
<div id="twelvetour">
<nav>
  <ul class="row">
     <li class="col-md-2">
         <div  class="twelveeffect">
             <a href="">
               <img class="img-responsive" src="" alt="" />
                <p class="text-center">LOREM IPSUM</p>
              </a>
         </div>

     </li>
     <li class="col-md-2">
        <div class="twelveeffect">
           <a href="">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="" alt="" />
            <p class="text-center">LOREM IPSUM</p>
           </a>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="col-md-2">
      <div class="twelveeffect">
         <a href="">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="" alt="" />
          <p class="text-center">LOREM IPSUM</p>
         </a>
      </div>                  
    </li>
 </ul>
</nav>
</div>
```

and this is my jquery:

```
 $("#twelvetour li>div.twelveeffect").hover(
 // Mouse Over
 function () {

  //problem is here
  $("#twelvetour li").css("zIndex",9 );

  $(this).animate({ width: '130%', height: 400 }, 500);
},
// Mouse Out
function () {


  $(this).animate({ width: '100%', height: 250 }, 500);


 });
```

as I mentioned my problem when I set `z-index` like this then it changes all of my list and again my hovered block overflow is behind it's brother but my goal is to have it front of it. and its very important for me when a block hovers, it didn't effect on the others place.

I tried some ways, some of them works in increasing but on decreasing after mouse over, the effect didn't work fine. it suddenly drops behind before 0.5s, it's width goes behind its brother. 
and my problem is for blocks in row not columns.

appreciate any help thanks.

Comment: Where is your `twelvetour` li in your html?

Comment: @krlzlx  I omit my code for shorthand but update now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
$(this).parent().css("zIndex",9);
```

instead of

```
$("#twelvetour li").css("zIndex",9);
```

on line 6 of your js

Comment: That is a little more complicated then what you have in your script. You would have to calculate the width / height of each element and than position these absolute on the page or in a container.

Than it would be possible to set a z-index and resize the elements on hover.

Comment: really thanks it solved with this change and plus this : $(this).animate({ width: '100%', height: 250 }, 500, function ()
      {
          $(this).parent().css("zIndex", 8);

      });

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too well versed in jquery but I hope my response will be helpful nonetheless. I find it much easier to do animations with native CSS.

In the below example, the div will expand its width on hover and contract when the user takes the cursor off the div.

The "transition" property tells the browser to animate any changes made to the element. So once we have that in place, we can just change the "width" property on hover and it will be nicely animated for us. We can do the same thing with "z-index".

you could alternatively use `transform: scale(1.2, 1);` to increase the width of an element without it affecting other elements in the list.

```css
.anAwesomeDiv {
   width: 100px;
   color: white;
   height: 100px;
   background-color: blue;
   transition: 0.5s;
 }

.anAwesomeDiv:hover {
   width: 200px;
   z-index: 50;
 }
```

```html
<div class="anAwesomeDiv">
  Look how awesome this div is!
</div>
```

Comment: really thanks but the problem is when it should be in list then by changing its width other elements of my list changes their place so that's not what I want

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#twelvetour li .twelveeffect").hover(
 // Mouse Over
 function (event) {

  //problem is here
 $(this).parent().css("zIndex",9);

  $(this).stop().animate({ width: '80%', height: 400 }, 500);
},
// Mouse Out
function (event) {


  $(this).stop(true,true).animate({ width: '40%', height: 50 }, 500);
  event.stopPropagation(); 
  event.preventDefault(); 

 });
```

```css
.twelveeffect {background:blue;color:white;width:30%;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="twelvetour">
<nav>
  <ul class="row">
     <li class="col-md-2">
         <div  class="twelveeffect">
             <a href="">
               <img class="img-responsive" src="" alt="" />
                <p class="text-center">LOREM IPSUM</p>
              </a>
         </div>

     </li>
     <li class="col-md-2">
        <div class="twelveeffect">
           <a href="">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="" alt="" />
            <p class="text-center">LOREM IPSUM</p>
           </a>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="col-md-2">
      <div class="twelveeffect">
         <a href="">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="" alt="" />
          <p class="text-center">LOREM IPSUM</p>
         </a>
      </div>                  
    </li>
 </ul>
</nav>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks but i don't want my other elemnts changes their place by hover the other one but thanks for your care

Comment: @ neda Derakhshesh . what you need. explain clearly.

Comment: thanks so much but the problem is not animation. if you look at the link while mouse hover each block the others didn't change their place. it seems it comes out of the list and get bigger. but still in this snippet the others changes . and also i don't have this problem in Horizontal list , I have this problem in verticals, the blocks which are in one row .

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can work with something like this:

```js
var li       = $('#twelvetour li');
var liWidth  = li.width();
var liLeft   = 0;
var liMargin  = 40;

li.each(function(){
  $(this).css({
    left : liLeft + 'px'
  });
  liLeft = liLeft + liWidth + liMargin;
});
```

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #555;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica sans-serif;
}

/*------------------------------------*/


#twelvetour {
  position: relative;
}

#twelvetour li {
  position: absolute;
  background: #e7e7e7;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 200ms ease;
  padding: 15px;
}

#twelvetour li p {
  margin: 0;
}

.twelveeffect {
  
}

#twelvetour li:hover {
  z-index: 3;
  padding: 30px;
  background: #1755ff;
  transform: translate(-15px);
  height: 300px;
  
}

#twelvetour li:hover a {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="twelvetour">
  <nav>
    <ul class="row">
       <li class="col-md-2">
           <div  class="twelveeffect">
               <a href="">
                 <img class="img-responsive" src="" alt="" />
                  <p class="text-center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
                </a>
           </div>

       </li>
       <li class="col-md-2">
          <div class="twelveeffect">
             <a href="">
              <img class="img-responsive" src="" alt="" />
              <p class="text-center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
             </a>
          </div>
      </li>
      <li class="col-md-2">
        <div class="twelveeffect">
           <a href="">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="" alt="" />
            <p class="text-center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
           </a>
        </div>                  
      </li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks but my list is in one  row not in a one column. my problem is when a block is changing it's width and it effect on its brothers in a row.